# Import of data from Teradata to SQL Server times out, regardless of Teradata timeout settings

Tags: sql-server, import, ssis, ssms, teradata

I am using the SQL Server Import and Export wizard to pull data from Teradata into a SQL Server table:

1. In SSMS, I right-click my target database and select "Import Data"
2. In "Choose a Data Source", I select ".NET Framework Data Provider for Teradata"
3. I change the Command Timeout and Connection Timeout to a high number, say, 3000 (I've also tried 0 and -1).
4. I set the SQL Server data source
5. I specify the query to select the data (query takes 15 min+ to run in Toad)
6. I set the option to create the destination table in SQL Server
7. I execute the package.
8. The package fails in pre-execute after ~40 seconds (error below).

I can run this query fine from an SSIS package in Visual Studio, or if I add it to a job. Setting the command timeout there makes a difference. I want to be able to run one-offs directly from SSMS, without going to the trouble of creating an SSIS package every time.

I have no connection timeout limit on the SQL Server side (set to 0).

### Error Text:

```
Pre-execute (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc0047062: Data Flow Task 1: Teradata.Client.Provider.TdException (0x80004005): [.NET Data Provider for Teradata] [100038] Command did not complete within the time specified (timeout).
[Teradata Database] [3110] The transaction was aborted by the user.
[Socket Transport] [115003] The receive operation timed out. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at Teradata.Client.Provider.WpTcpTransport.ReadLanHeader(Buffer buffer, Int32 timeout, Int32 readBytes)
   at Teradata.Client.Provider.WpTcpTransport.ReadLanHeader(Buffer buffer, Int32 timeout, Int32 readBytes)
   at Teradata.Client.Provider.WpTcpTransport.Receive(Buffer buffer, Int32 timeout)
   at Teradata.Client.Provider.WpSession.Receive(Buffer buffer, Int32 timeout)
   at Teradata.Client.Provider.WpMessageManager.Receive(Int32 timeout)
   at Teradata.Client.Provider.WpStartRequestManager.ReceiveStartMessage()
   at Teradata.Client.Provider.WpStartRequestManager.Action(ManagerActions step)
   at Teradata.Client.Provider.WpStartRequestManager.RedriveAction(ManagerActions step)
   at Teradata.Client.Provider.WpStartRequestManager.Action()
   at Teradata.Client.Provider.Request.ExecuteStartRequest(String commandText, TeraTypeBase[][] parameters, ExecutionMode executionMode, Boolean asynchronous, Boolean isTrustedRequest)
   at Teradata.Client.Provider.TdCommand.ExecuteRequest(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, Boolean asynchronousCall)
   at Teradata.Client.Provider.TdCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Teradata.Client.Provider.TdCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.DataReaderSourceAdapter.PreExecute()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPreExecute(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper) (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc004701a: Data Flow Task 1: Source - Query failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0x80004005.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Information 0x4004300b: Data Flow Task 1: "Destination - MercTestTeradataPull" wrote 0 rows.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

Comment: Try to use the ODBC provider (OLE DB provider for ODBC drivers) instead. I have a linked server connected through it, never timing out.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, @Quicksilver wondering if you have figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and just figured out and works for me. Open the SSIS package, find "command time out" which was by default hard coded by SQL in 30 secs. Change it to the time you want then save it. Then it all runs fine.